# select the data of all the students scoring highest marks in each subject group by city

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I am using mysql version 8.0.23

the given table is:-

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-------+-----------|
| id  | name   | subject   | marks | city      |
+-----+--------+-----------+-------+-----------|
| 101 | ravi   | maths     |    70 | Mumbai    |
| 103 | Viaan  | english   |    26 | Bangalore |
| 104 | varun  | chemistry |    95 | delhi     |
| 105 | rishab | biology   |    69 | delhi     |
|  108| Mihika | maths     |    78 | Kolkata   |
|  110| Ishaan | english   |    39 | Bangalore |
+-----+--------+-----------+-------+-----------|
```

and I want to get the complete data of the students having highest marks in each subject from each city

```
select subject, city, max(marks) as highest
from students
group by subject, city
order by subject, city;
```

--

```
select subject
     , city
     , max(marks) as highest 
  from students 
 group 
    by subject
     , city 
 order 
    by subject
     , city;

+-----------+-----------+---------+
| subject   | city      | highest |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| biology   | Bangalore |      87 |
| biology   | Chennai   |      58 |
| biology   | delhi     |      82 |
| biology   | Jaipur    |      52 |
| biology   | Kolkata   |      92 |
| biology   | Lucknow   |      98 |
| chemistry | Bangalore |      84 |
| chemistry | Chennai   |      64 |
| chemistry | delhi     |      95 |
| chemistry | Jaipur    |      83 |
| chemistry | Kolkata   |      45 |
| chemistry | Lucknow   |     100 |
| chemistry | Mumbai    |      87 |
```

I had used this but still I am not able to see name and id of that student

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: The reason why users here prefers formatted text are many. 1. If only one needs to transcribe it, that is preferable. You already have access to the data in text, so please just give that. 2. Lots of users cannot see the images. Also please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way using window functions:

```
select * from 
   ( 
    select * , rank() over (partition by subject, city order by mark desc) rn
    from yourtable
   ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support ,

Comment: where should I add table name (students) because it says no table selected

Comment: yes now it works few thank you very much,  select * from     (      select * , rank() over (partition by subject, city order by marks desc) rn     from students
) t where rn = 1;

Comment: I think it would have been preferable if you had explained what is going on in your query. For example how rank works and how it partitions the data. Also the meta you linked to doesn't seem to say how to easily create an ascii table, but is about tables in commonmark.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select s.* from students s, (select subject, city, max(marks) as highest from students as b group by subject, city  order by subject, city) b where (s.city=b.city and s.subject=b.subject and s.marks=b.highest) order by city,subject;
```

I used the above query this is also giving answer